# CSS filter over whole site

Tags: html, css

I want to put a sepia filter over my whole page.
In Chrome everything works fine but in other browsers (tested Firefox) only divs get the filter applied, empty spots stay the same. How can i achieve a filter over the whole site?
I am using this code:

```css
html {
    -webkit-filter: sepia(15%);
    filter: sepia(15%);
}
```

I'm working with bootstrap studio btw

Comment: Is your page less that 100% of the viewport in height? If so, try `body { min-height: 100vh; }`.

Comment: Also, a note: use `filter` which is the standard property. `-webkit-filter` is an older syntax that Firefox kindly aliases, but you should be using `filter`, and the other browser variants should be specified before for better support.

Comment: My body is already 100% of the viewport. I also included `filter` i just forgot to mention it in the question.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what's happening so we can better understand the "empty spots" you mentioned?

Comment: I dont know why the question got flagged as duplicate. Applying the filter to body does not solve the issue.

Comment: the duplicate is saying MORE than simply *apllying the filter to body*. By the way you question lack code and will get closed in all the cases